# join should show both match and not matched distinct records

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables one representing cases another representing units.
I want to join in such way that if same txn_key is there for both it should join and cases and units should be in same row and if not matched then those should also be in the same table but corresponding missed cases/units should be empty or null

[image]

Answer (score 0):

select * from table1 full outer join
table2 on table1.txn_key=table2.txn_key

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
select isnull(f1.txn_key, f2.txn_key) as txn_key
isnull(f1.pr_cd, f2.pr_cd) as pr_cd,
f1.type, f1.units as cases,
f2.type, f2.units as type
from yourtable1 f1 full outer join yourtable2 f2
on f1.txn_key=f2.txn_key
```